# force boxes in R Shiny to have same height

Tags: r, shiny, box

I have several boxes which are located in a fluid-row,  When these boxes contain similar amounts of information there is no issue with the height alignment, and the dynamic adjustment of this height with a smaller browser window works fine.

The issue comes when the boxes do not contain the same amount of information (e.g. two tables next to each other with differing numbers of rows); this causes the heights to not line up neatly.

```
# NOT RUN {
## Only run this example in interactive R sessions
if (interactive()) {
  library(shiny)

  # A dashboard body with a row of infoBoxes and valueBoxes, and two rows of boxes
  body <- dashboardBody(

    # infoBoxes




    # Boxes
    fluidRow(
      box(status = "primary",
          sliderInput("orders", "Orders", min = 1, max = 2000, value = 650),
          selectInput("progress", "Progress",
                      choices = c("0%" = 0, "20%" = 20, "40%" = 40, "60%" = 60, "80%" = 80,
                                  "100%" = 100)
          )
      ),
      box(title = "Histogram box title",
          status = "warning", solidHeader = TRUE, collapsible = TRUE,
          plotOutput("plot", height = 250)
      )
    )


  )

  server <- function(input, output) {



    output$plot <- renderPlot({
      hist(rnorm(input$orders))
    })
  }

  shinyApp(
    ui = dashboardPage(
      dashboardHeader(),
      dashboardSidebar(),
      body
    ),
    server = server
  )
}
# }
```

I know I can manually set the height of the boxes, but the issue comes when I do not know the amount of information needed to be presented in each box. I do not want to make the box too short (and potentially cut out information), nor do I want to make the box too tall (and use too much screen space). However I do want the boxes to be the same height.

Therefore, is it possible to extract the dynamically generated max height of each box and use that height to force both boxes to that height?

This would be important to me when the boxes contain differing amount of information, and when the screen is resized and [for example] the text of one box jumps to two lines but the other box does not (causing mis-matched height).

Comment: Please provide us with some code.

Answer (score 1):

This may work

```
# NOT RUN {
## Only run this example in interactive R sessions
if (interactive()) {
  library(shiny)

  # A dashboard body with a row of infoBoxes and valueBoxes, and two rows of boxes
  body <- dashboardBody(

    # infoBoxes




    # Boxes
    fluidRow(
      box(status = "primary", style="position:relative;width:100%;height:0;padding-bottom:62.75%;", 
          sliderInput("orders", "Orders", min = 1, max = 2000, value = 650),
          selectInput("progress", "Progress",
                      choices = c("0%" = 0, "20%" = 20, "40%" = 40, "60%" = 60, "80%" = 80,
                                  "100%" = 100)
          )
      ),
      box(title = "Histogram box title", style="position:relative;width:100%;height:0;padding-bottom:56.25%;", 
          status = "warning", solidHeader = TRUE, collapsible = TRUE,
          plotOutput("plot", height = 250)
      )
    )


  )

  server <- function(input, output) {



    output$plot <- renderPlot({
      hist(rnorm(input$orders))
    })
  }

  shinyApp(
    ui = dashboardPage(
      dashboardHeader(),
      dashboardSidebar(),
      body
    ),
    server = server
  )
}
```

play around with the padding-bottom percentage if you want to change the height.

I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for providing a Solution, however this is more of a manual adjustment which can also be done by setting the height. I was more searching for an automatic adjustment or setting all the box sized to be maximum for each fluid row

Comment: Hi @Raha, if you want the box size to be the maximum for each row you can set the padding-bottom to 100% (one will be smaller though because it doesn't have a header). Sorry I can't be of more help, I hope you find a solution